# Are official packages always a better choice than PPA?

Tags: 16.04, backup

I would need to install the `borgbackup` package into a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04.
The official package is version 1.0.11. 
I noticed that version 1.0.11 does not have the the `borg diff` command, as far as I know introduced with version 1.1.0. The current stable [borg](https://www.borgbackup.org/) version is 1.1.3. 
 I wonder why the official package is so outdated and if it could be convenient to install `borg` from PPA.

Comment: A lot of testing needs to be done before these packages are incorporated but if you need to install via PPA...

Comment: "Is X a better choice than Y?" is a subjective question, off topic because the answer is personal preference for the most part. Any packages you install is a contract of trust between you, the packager, and the software authors. Which is "better" depends on which is more trustworthy for you. As for "why is the latest version not in the official release from 2 years ago" sort of questions, there is another question for that which has been answered. Constantly updating every application to the latest version in every released version of Ubuntu, is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install software directly from its website, which is often the only viable choice, as when the repository version is too outdated and you have no reason to trust the PPA. This is, however, advised against by Debian (on which Ubuntu is based) because you then can’t uninstall the software with dpkg/apt and because of the risk of package conflicts.

As to your question of why packages become outdated: packaging for Debian/Ubuntu is hard. To get a package accepted, you have to be able to build the package from source in controlled conditions, using only libraries that have previously been packaged for Debian/Ubuntu under these conditions. You also have to comply with a range of other policies. It can take a lot of work to manipulate a complex piece of software into meeting these requirements, and newer versions of software raise new packaging challenges.

Also, there may only be one maintainer for a given package; if they for any reason stop being able to maintain the package, updates stop.

Ultimately I’ll have to echo Marc in saying that this is a judgement call that varies from case to case, depending on what you need from a given package.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the package, the PPA, your need for security, and your tolerance for downtime while you sort out problems.

- The official packages are less likely to create conflicts with other
  packages that you have to sort out.
- The official packages are less likely to have any security problems
  than those from a PPA you know little about.
- The official packages are more likely to be out of date, sometimes by
  years, lacking features and fixes.
- The official packages may not include software you want.

There really is no answer to you question, only a judgement call you have to make.